# Running karma on Safari painfully slow

Tags: performance, safari, teamcity, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

We use teamcity to run our client side unit tests with Karma.

The tests run on IE,Firefox,Chrome and Safari. The problem is that when Safari is running the 2500 tests it takes around 1 hour to complete the tests. The other browsers finish in a few minutes.

It runs on Safari 8.0.8 (Mac OS X 10.10.5), karma version 0.13.9

Have anyone experienced the same problem and got any solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are using TeamCity to run client side tests with Karma too.

We are experiencing the same performance problems with Safari 7.1.8 (Mac OS X 10.9.5), but only when the screen is off or the screen saver is active. In these cases Safari runs the tests and then remains open and idle. When the screen is on all works fine.

Our current workaround is to keep the screen of the iMac running the tests always on.

Apart from the screen/screen saver, another possible cause of performance issues (for all browsers) is App Nap. We disabled it for the browser we use for testing.

Comment: Thank you! It turned out this was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We also had this exact same issue and the App Nap answer did not solve it for us. Though shortly after we did finally get it to run consistently fast.
So I hope the following list of actions might be useful for some other poor soul whom may also have spent stupid amounts of time trying to solve this.

Our current setup for the TeamCity build agent and the Mac itself that hosts is are as follows.

1. **Having the build agent setup in the way [recommended by jetbrains](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Setting+up+and+Running+Additional+Build+Agents#SettingupandRunningAdditionalBuildAgents-AutomaticAgentStartunderMacOSx)**, if you set up the build agent for pre 9.0 versions of TeamCity the recommended way of doing it was different and gave problems with various type of GUI related activities.
2. **Disabling App Nap for good measure**, as mentioned this didn't make a difference for us but reading about it after finding it here points that it may be worthwhile to do. If you want to do it globally on the computer (which we did) run the following in the terminal:

   defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSAppSleepDisabled -bool YES
3. **Disable the Mac [Display Sleep](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201714)**, this was the clincher for us. I saw that whenever Safari started running slow again the screen had turned off on the Mac in question (as in having entered power saving mode). So after disabling that the Safari runs have now been running consistently fast.